# How do I refresh JTable with ActionListener in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I want to refresh two dimensional array table in my `JFrame` with `ActionListener`. Here is some codes from my program:

```
public Students(){
     .....
     removeall = new JMenuItem("Remove All Students");
     removeall.addActionListener(this);
     .....
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource().equals(removeall)) {
        removeAll();
        table.repaint();
}

public void removeAll() {

    for(int i=name1.size()-1;i>=0;i--) 
    {
        lastname1.remove(i);
        id1.remove(i);
        quiz11.remove(i);
        quiz21.remove(i);
        midterm1.remove(i);
        project1.remove(i);
        final1.remove(i);
        lettergrade1.remove(i);
        average1.remove(i);
        name1.remove(i);
        tablemodel.removeRow(i);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All students are removed. ");
}
```

As you see, I have tried `repaint()` and `tableModel.fireTableDataChanged()` and both of them didn't work. What should I do to refresh my table? And also here is a picture:

It doesn't refresh:

[image: It doesn't refresh]

Comment: Please see edits to answer. Again, if this does not answer the question, then please post your own [mcve].

Comment: replace `table.repaint()` with `table.fireTableDataChanged()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is impossible to answer precisely since you haven't posted a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to compile and run, but it looks like you're trying to change the state of a collection that was used to initialize a JTable's model without changing the actual model itself.

Having said that, to remove all the data from a JTable, remove all the rows. If you're using a DefaultTableModel, then this means simply calling `.setRowCount(0)` on the model.

Note that there is no need to call `repaint()` in this situation since by changing the model, repaint is automatically called. Also your code shouldn't even attempt to call `fireTableDataChanged()` on the model, since this type of call should be called internally by the model itself only.

For example, my MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableExample {
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TablePanel tablePanel = new TablePanel();
        JMenuItem fillTableItem = new JMenuItem(new FillTableAction(tablePanel));
        JMenuItem clearTableItem = new JMenuItem(new ClearTableAction(tablePanel));

        JMenu tableMenu = new JMenu("Table Actions");
        tableMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        tableMenu.add(fillTableItem);
        tableMenu.add(clearTableItem);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(tableMenu);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tablePanel);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class FillTableAction extends AbstractAction {
    private TablePanel tablePanel;

    public FillTableAction(TablePanel tablePanel) {
        super("Fill Table");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_F);
        this.tablePanel = tablePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tablePanel.fillTable();
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ClearTableAction extends AbstractAction {
    private TablePanel tablePanel;

    public ClearTableAction(TablePanel tablePanel) {
        super("Clear Table");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
        this.tablePanel = tablePanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tablePanel.clearTable();
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TablePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "Name", "Surname", "ID" };
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COL_NAMES, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private Random random = new Random();

    public TablePanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public void clearTable() {
        model.setRowCount(0);
    }

    // fill it with random text and data
    public void fillTable() {
        int rows = random.nextInt(50) + 40;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char c = (char) ('A' + random.nextInt(26));
            sb.append(c);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 + random.nextInt(3); j++) {
                sb.append((char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26)));
            }
            String name = sb.toString();

            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
            sb.append((char) ('A' + random.nextInt(26)));
            for (int j = 0; j < 6 + random.nextInt(4); j++) {
                sb.append((char) ('a' + random.nextInt(26)));
            }
            String surName = sb.toString();

            int id = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);

            Object[] rowData = { name, surName, id };
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But again, if this answer doesn't answer your question, create and post your [mcve] (MCVE).

Comment: Thank you for help. I solved problem with tablemodel.removeRow(i); code in the end of for loop.